# video size inside embedded wmv (windows media player) object

Tags: html, video, wmv

how can I change the sizes of the content inside an object (wmv video embed)?
The problem is, that a object-tag has a size of 400x400px and the video too but it looks like the following:
[image]

How can I set the video into the full black container?

Code:

```
            <object id="animation" classid="clsid:6BF52A52-394A-11d3-B153-00C04F79FAA6" type="application/x-oleobject" src="testvideo.wmv" style="width:400px;height:400px">
                <param name="EnableContextMenu" value="0">
                <param name="wmode" value="opaque">
                <param name="ShowControls" value="true">
                <param name="autostart" value="false">
                <param name="AutoSize" value="false">
                <param name="Loop" value="0">
            </object>
```

Comment: Can you post sample code demonstrating the issue?

Comment: I have postet the code above. unfortunately I can´t post the video, because it is secret... You have to replace testvideo.wmv

Comment: The problem isn´t solved yet. I saw the "problem" on other sites. So this is probably default by WMV-Player. But how to change this?